# Play Framework Enumerator : How can you zip enumerator with Index

Tags: scala, playframework, enumerator

Lets say I have an Enumerator

val e: Enumerator[String] = Enumerator("a","b","c")

and another enumerator of natural numbers

val count = Enumerator.enumerate(Iterator.from(1))

How could I generate an Enumerator that zips both of them. Or zips e with index.
So in this case output being: 
val zipped: Enumerator[(String,Int)] = Enumerator(("a",1),("b",2),("c",3))

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat new to Iteratees but since there are no responses yet, I will share my less than expert knowledge.

It seems like there should be a zip operator that does what you describe. The closest is `interleave`, but based on my understanding of its behavior, I don't think it will fit you use case.

If you just need an index for each element you could use something like this (I acknowledge the ugly mutable state)

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import play.api.libs.iteratee._

scala> var counter = -1
counter: Int = -1

scala> Enumerator("a", "b", "c").map[(String, Int)]{ s => counter+=1; (s, counter) }
res1: play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator[(String, Int)] = play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator$$anon$3@3c0c6967

scala> res1 run Iteratee.foreach( println _ )
(a,0)
(b,1)
res2: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@7814bb7d
(c,2)

scala>
```

If you want something that doesn't close around a `var` (as you should!) you could look into implementing this functionality on the side of the iteratee and pass the counter around as state in the `Step` process.